# Must my swift function's return type inherit from NSObject

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have some swift function in a swift object of type `Helper` that returns an object of class `Parameter`.  `Parameter` is defined as:

```
class Parameter { }
```

And my function like this:

```
func getParameter() -> Parameter { }
```

When accessing the methods from `Helper` only those that don't return anything show up.  However, `getParameter` is uncallable.  My assumption is that its return type is invisible to Obj-C.  Must `Parameter` extend NSObject in order to work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have your Swift classes available to Objective-C, they must inherit from an Objective-C bridged class. That's why your ViewControllers are always available, and for free-standing classes, you must make their superclass `NSObject`. You can also specifically note in code they are bridged by marking them: `@objc class Parameter: NSObject{}`